# how can i use " id = tostring(i) " in Corona and Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i recently saw something like this

```
if(ebasRating_Arr[i] == 0) then
        radioButton_0 = widget.newSwitch {
            left = 565,
            style = "radio",
            initialSwitchState = true,
            id = tostring(i),
            width = 60,
            height = 60,
            onPress = setEBASRating0
        }
        radioGroup:insert( radioButton_0 )

        radioButton_1 = widget.newSwitch {
            style = "radio",
            id = tostring(i),
            initialSwitchState = false,
            width = 60,
            height = 60,
            onPress = setEBASRating1
        }
        radioGroup:insert( radioButton_1 )
```

notice the "id = tostring(i)" in line 6 and 13. So i am experimenting this id = tostring(i) wanting to find out what it means. Can someone tell me what it really means? SO the second part of my question how can i use something like id = tostring(i) in my code here

```
 local madrs = display.newGroup()
local function textListener( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

elseif ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "submitted" ) then
    -- Output resulting text from "defaultField"

print( event.target.text )

elseif ( event.phase == "editing" ) then
    print( event.newCharacters )
    print( event.oldText )
    print( event.startPosition )
    print( event.text )
    end
end
```

Comment: https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-tostring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *i* is a number in the *for* loop you used.The id of the button should be in *string* format so that it will be identified by corona sdk as a *name* for things like scenes.Example

```
   composer.gotoScene("level"..tostring(event.target.id),{effect="fade"});
```

The above line goes to a scene named level1,if the id of the button is 1.It should not be an integer or float.It should be a string so that corona sdk will treat it as a *name* of a scene

Bro i don't understand you question or the second code(since i havenot learnt about radio buttons),But let me share what i know....Say that you want to know the id of the radioButton_0  and convert it into number.The code will be like below

```
print(radioButton_0.id); --> prints a string (0) --
print(tonumber(radioButton_0.id));--> prints a number (0)
```

I dont know about radio buttons.If you tell me your motive(application) of your above code,I can help

Comment: so how would you implement id = tostring(i) in the 2nd code above?

Comment: I am sure i dont know anything about the radio buttons.But let me tell.....